# Adding a node to a NIFI cluster with embedded Zookeeper

Tags: apache-nifi, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a 3 node nifi cluster, using embedded Zookeeper. Now I need to add a new node to the cluster. What is the procedure for the same?
Will I have to bring down all the nodes, since I need to add an entry to the /nifi/conf/zookeeper.conf(server=) and also to the list of zookeeper servers in /nifi/conf/nifi.properties(nifi.zookeeper.connect.string). As far as I understand, these both will have to be edited on the existing 3 as well as the new box. But dont think this is the right way, since each time the cluster will have to be brought down. Can someone please help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would have three or five ZooKeeper nodes, so if you already have three then you don't really need to add a fourth. You could add another NiFi node that uses the existing embedded ZooKeepers on the other nodes.

Comment: For other peoples reference, a more detailed explanation can be found here: https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/226058/adding-a-node-to-a-nifi-cluster-with-embedded-zook.html?childToView=226113